# Which sensors will best suited for indoor/outdoor SLAM system with high accuracy of localization?

Tags: ros, localilzation, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need a SLAM system for mobile platform which will be used in on-site construction.

We are to build a 3D map from clouds of points and need localization in it.

We don’t need fast localization, but we need high accuracy of localization, error of localization should be around 1mm at a distance up to 5 meters.

Which sensor will suit for this - maybe it will be enough only a stereo vision (can it give us required accuracy?), or only LiDAR sensor (what’s about accuracy and usage in direct sunlight?) or we need to use something different and combine several type of sensors?

Can you advise the best solution for this task?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258643/which-sensors-will-best-suited-for-indoor/outdoor-slam-system-with-high-accuracy-of-localization?/) by [milif777](https://answers.ros.org/users/29939/milif777/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As NEngelhard says, 1mm is hard to achieve. Check out [this paper](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/publications/papers/roewekaemper12iros.pdf), where the authors try to achieve maximum accuracy with laser scanners.

Accurate localization requires a precise map, so maybe try an approach as described in [this paper](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/publications/papers/ruhnke11icra.pdf)

Stereo vision has measurement noise that grows quadratically with distance, therefore you won't get that good accuracy unless the distance to obstacles is always in a specific range.

Laser scanners have different inaccuracies. For example, from what I heard from users, SICK scanners are more accurate than Hokuyo, but this might be model dependent.

Fusion of different sensors usually improves results. But also using more than one of the same type may be advantageous. The guys in the first paper use two laser scanners, with opposite viewing direction, which helps a lot.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2